# Spinner is not showing in modal for async function c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, modal-dialog, task

I need to generate monthly report, So I have modal, inside the modal, user can select which range of monthly report they want to generate, then after user click OK button, the spinner should display while the process is taking place behind(generate report for that month). but my spinner is not showing..

**MY HTML- MODAL**

```
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: Black">Generate Monthly</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>

                                </p>                                   
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="generateMonthly" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="generateMonthly_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    CssClass="rbGenerate">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Jan-April" Value="1" />
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="May - August" Value="2" />
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Sept - December" Value="3" />
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>                              


                                <div id="divSpinner" align="center" runat="server">
                                    Processing. Please wait.<br />
                                    <br />
                                    <img src="../build/images/loading.gif" alt="" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="saveGenerate" class="btn btn-success" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="hideGenerate" class="btn btn-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**MY CODE BEHIND**

```
public void saveGenerate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ENTERED saveGenerate n start spinner");
    divSpinner.Visible = true;


    Task task = GenerateReport();
    task.Wait();
     Debug.WriteLine("done");

    Debug.WriteLine("SHOWING THIS AFTER GENERATE_MONTH PROCESS  FINISH");

    divSpinner.Visible = false;
}
```

**GenerateReport code**

```
 public async Task GenerateReport()
{
//selected radiobutton(month range)
//executing query - to generate report based on selected month and saved into table
 Debug.WriteLine("Process complete");


 await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

My problem is , the spinner is not showing.I have tried to refer other answers, and still not working.

Comment: your `<div id="divSpinner"` is not showing or image in same div is not showing?

Comment: yes i mean, divSpinner is not showing, because if i set it to divSpinner.visible = true only, it will show me the image, but if i add the next line (Task task = GenerateReport();) it is not showing anymore

Comment: so could you add your full code of `GenerateReport` in question so i have to check what actually issue

Comment: means initially its showing but whenever `GenerateReport` method called its suddenly stopped showing right ?

Comment: yes, it stop showing once i add GenerateReport, is it because of my async function usage, maybe i doing it wrong way?

Comment: try to add you code inside `GenerateReport` so what causes actually to stop showing spinner

Comment: here from my side I hide line `await Task.Delay(1000);` from `GenerateReport` and then all are working good, so try at your end may it works

Comment: hi ii hve tried to remove that line, but the spinner is still not displaying, let me check my GenerateReport code n i ll add the code here :)

Comment: try to add `generateMonthly_SelectedIndexChanged` code also

Comment: did u get rid form your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The expected behaviour would be correct for a client application (such as Winforms or WPF), this is a web application though. The *saveGenerate* event is processed server side and the result is sent to the client as HTTP response only after the request has finished. This is why you won't see the spinner appear in the browser. Note that on the server the tasks are processed asynchronously. A solution would be to show the spinner using client side Javascript just before calling the server. A server side solution is to flush your response just after making the spinner visible (`Response.Body.Flush`).